# Should I -keep models from obfuscating when using ProGuard and GSON's @SerializedName("")?

Tags: android, gson, proguard

I'm configuring ProGuard to obfuscate my code. 
I'm also using GSON to serialize/deserialize JSON. All my fields are annotated with `@SerializedName("")`. Is GSON still using reflection in this case?

According to the GSON ProGuard config sample all models should be kept. This is due to reflection I guess?
https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg

```
# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
```

But when I don't keep my models and obfuscate them all, everything seems to work fine.

1. Is GSON using reflection when I use `@SerializedName("")`
2. Is it safe to obfuscate all my models and don't add the `-keep` configuration?

Comment: you might just need the member (field) names.

Comment: some recommendations here: https://medium.com/google-developers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. [This comment](https://medium.com/@wkalicinski/thats-true-but-i-d-say-it-s-not-the-intended-use-of-those-annotations-the-fact-that-it-protects-87cff32c650d) indicates that it works with `@SerializedName("")` but that this is a side effect. I'm going to `-keep`my models, this will be safer for the future.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the link!